# If the Kullback-Leibler distance between f and g is zero then f = g almost surely

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, kullback-leibler

If the Kullback-Leibler distance between f and g is zero then f = g almost surely. I am really having trouble solving this. It should be simple!

Comment: Have you had a look at [Gibb's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality)?

Comment: Not sure how to use it!

Comment: Apparentely, Jensen's inequality holds with equality if and only if the random variable is a point mass. Now I have to prove this! It's so hard to find a proof for this!

Comment: Extend the [Wikipedia demonstration for discrete variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality#Proof) to the continuous case.